# Cognito Group Permission Dynamically from Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I created a cognito pool

Created users

Created 2 Groups **WITHOUT** any IAM roles

Assigned users to 2 different groups.

I store policies for a group in database and cache them .

In the lambda authorizer that has been  configured , the deny policy works with principalId set to a random string.

For allowing access , i set the principal Id to the cognito User name. I get the policy from the database with permissions allowed for all api gateway end points. ( For testing )
But even after this i get the "User is not authorized" message.

Is my understanding wrong ? What am i doing wrong.

This is my policy for allowing access with the userId being the cognito user name.

```
authResponse = {}

authResponse['principalId'] = userId
authResponse['policyDocument'] = {

        'Version': '2012-10-17',
        'Statement': [
            {
                'Sid': 'FirstStatement',
                'Action': 'execute-api:Invoke',
                'Effect': 'Allow',
                'Resource': 'arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:ppg7tavcld/test/GET/test-api-1/users/*'
            }
        ]
    }

return authResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry . this was a mistake from me.
It was solved due to mixing up the stage position in the Resource